# How DC authenticates when Client is not using any authentication?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, authentication, windows-authentication

I have a virtual environment with the following structure:

- DC: Windows Server 2008
- Client: Windows 7

I installed Active Directory on the Windows Server 2008 and made it in domain `januapp.local`, then I joined the client which uses local authentication with username and password `utkarsh` to the domain by using the DC administrator username and password. It perfectly added it to the domain `januapp.local`.

So, when I restart the client machine and logged in using the same username and password, `utkarsh`, it logged me into the domain `januapp.local`. So, all was good there.

### Problem Starts here

But, then I tried to join my main domain on Windows 10 to the same domain `januapp.local` using the administrator username and password.

**Note: On that Windows 10, I didn't set any authentication to log me in.**

When I restart the PC, on the main screen I got `another user` new login option in right lower left. When I go there it asks me to type the **authentication credentials to join januapp**.

At that point I didn't have any special authentication credentials; I only used the administrator username and password to join Windows to the domain.

Are the administrator username and password required? I tried, but it says username and password are not valid.

**Then, what kind of username and password are required?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. When you logged onto the workstation with the local user account you did NOT log into the domain. Your workstation is joined to the domain but your local user is NOT logged into the domain.
2. If you want to log into the domain then you need to create a user account in the domain. You then need to log into the domain from your workstation with the domain user account.
3. You can very well log into the domain from your workstation with the domain Administrator user account. There's nothing preventing you from doing that.

Comment: Okay, so when I logged with the local user account, the user didn't log in the domain but the workstation is. For user and workstation login in I have to create a user and password in the users 'OU' in DC? If is that Correct then I have two questions?

Comment: Question:- Then How the credentials were identified to whom client? For ex:- let's say a user is in the domain with username:- utkarsh password:-test and there are TWO clients with computer name is "ABC" "PQR" then Are they both can use the same username and password? **Please clarify it.**

Comment: Question2:- When I tried to login with administrator username and password *which was the user of DC domain*. But I got an error **that your account has been locked please ask to the administrator.**

Comment: I hope you will reply to all these queries. Thanks @joeqwerty

Comment: Can I get any reply from you?

Comment: For your first question the answer is Yes. A user can log into the domain from multiple domain-joined computers simultaneously. For your second question, it should be obvious what the problem is. The user account is locked out.